# code highlighting inside textAngular wysiwyg

Tags: angularjs

I have articles, that contain inner programming code.
I used angular-highlightjs for hilight code in frontend, such as:

```
<div hljs>
<!-- put your codes here -->
</div>
```

It works fine!

Now I include textAngular for CREATE/UPDATE articles in admin panel, but it erases my "hljs" directive from input articles.

What should I do to fix it? or suggest me angular wysiwyg with code highlight support.

**UPD:**
Thanks for advice, 
this code work fine:

```
        .config(function($provide){
        $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', '$compile', '$rootScope', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions, $compile, $rootScope){
            taRegisterTool('hljs', {
                iconclass: "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open",
                tooltiptext: "code highlighting",
                action: function() {
                    var selectedText = window.getSelection();
                    var  hljsTag = '<div hljs>'+ selectedText +'</div>';
                    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
                    var element = $compile(hljsTag)(scope);
                    return this.$editor().wrapSelection('insertHTML', element.html(), true);
                }
            });
            taOptions.toolbar[1].push('hljs');
            return taOptions;
        }]);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own toolbar button in textAngular for that like this:

```
module.config(function($provide){
$provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions){
    // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating
    // register the tool with textAngular
    taRegisterTool('colourRed', {
        iconclass: "fa fa-square red",
        action: function(){
            this.$editor().wrapSelection('forecolor', 'red');
        }
    });
    // add the button to the default toolbar definition
    taOptions.toolbar[1].push('colourRed');
    return taOptions;
}]);
```

});

This button will make your selected content in textAngular editor red.

Go to https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar for more info